# Page break with minted: code gets out of background

Tags: minted

I'm using minted for displaying C++ code. If there is a long line at the bottom of the page, the line breaks as expected. Unfortunately there is also a gray arrow to indicate the line break.[image: output]

How can I prevent this?

Edit: Here's a MWE to reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\setminted[c++]{breaklines,bgcolor=bg}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{c++}
#include <iostream>

int main() {
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
std::cout << "Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World" std::endl;
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Could you show a MWE to reproduce this problem.

Comment: @Tom I added a MWE, sorry I didn't do that in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

`minted` package `bgcolor` scheme was not robust at page break. See [manual](https://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) page. 22.

> Be aware that if bgcolor is used with
> breaklines=true, and a line break occurs just before a page break, then text may
> extend below the colored background in some instances. It is best to use a more
> advanced framing package in those cases

I recommend you use `tcolorbox` package which even provides a built-in framing environment with minted support. An example as follow:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.h}
#include <iostream>

int main() {

std::cout << "Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World" std::endl;
}
\end{filecontents*}
%\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,breakable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
%\setminted[c++]{breaklines,bgcolor=bg}
\begin{document}
%\begin{minted}{c++}
\begin{tcblisting}{
colback=bg,
breakable,
listing only,
minted language=c++,
minted options={breaklines}}
#include <iostream>

int main() {
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
std::cout << "Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World" std::endl;
}
\end{tcblisting}
%\end{minted}
\tcbinputlisting{
colback=bg,
breakable,
listing only,
listing file={test.h},
minted language=c++,
minted options={breaklines}}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is it also possible to add a whole file, like you would with the \inputminted command?

Comment: @RaphBilder Yes. You could use `\tcbinputlisting{⟨options⟩}`. More info you can check `tcolorbox` manual https://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf . I will  add an example in the answer.